# a global place to set header height of stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I have created a Stack navigator:

```
const MyScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const MyStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <MyStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName=...
      screenOptions={{headerShown: true}}>
      <MyStack.Screen
        name=“MyScreen”
        component={MyScreen}
        options={{
          title: ‘Hello’,
          headerLeft: () => <Image...>,
        }}
      />
    </MyStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

As you can see above, I have specified to show header & show `headerLeft` image. But how can I set the header height for all screens hosted by this stack navigator?  Is there a global place to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the height using the header styles in screenOptions like below

```
<MyStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: true,
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'tomato', height: 20 },
  }}>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the screenOptions prop on `Stack.Navigator`. (See it in the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#sharing-common-options-across-screens))

Something like this:

```
<Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerLeft: () => <Image...>,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ title: 'My home' }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```